# Ejecución lenta de script usando cx_oracle en segunda ejecución despues de error

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle

Soy nuevo en Python y estoy teniendo un problema al ejecutar un script en Python 3.6, el cual utiliza ***cx_oracle*** en su version 6.1

El problema es que en la primera ejecución de el script todo va muy bien, las consultas a la base de datos son rápidas, pero si el el script se llega a detener por un error, al intentar de nuevo ejecutar el script se queda pegado mucho tiempo realizando las mismas consultas que ya realizó, utilizando cProfile me dice que cx_oracle.cursor():

```
43  111.284    2.588  111.284    2.588 {method 'execute' of 'cx_Oracle.Cursor' objects}
```

La estructura del código es esta:

```
gamble_conexion = cx_Oracle.connect('usuario', 'pass', 'ip')
cursor_gamble =  gamble_conexion.cursor()


def metodouno():
    cursor_gamble.execute(sql)
    for r in cursor_gamble.fetchall():
        # se añaden a unas lista



def metododos():
    # se ultiliza el mismo cursor para realizar otro tipo de consultas,este mismo procedimiento se executa en otro metodos

# al final del script
cursor_gamble.close()
gamble_conexion.close()
```

En la primera ejecución se puede demorar 11 minutos y en la segunda si se llega a detener el proceso, se puede tardar hasta 30. El tiempo promedio que se demora el script son 13 minutos, ya que le realiza unos cálculos de venta con miles de registros clasificando y realizando promedios en diferentes tablas.